# Creation date of Exchange 2010 archive mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010

Exchange 2010 can answer when a user's primary mailbox was created.

```
[PS] C:\WINDOWS\system32>Get-Mailbox finn2617 |select whencreated

WhenCreated
-----------
05-May-15 10:25:26 AM
```

My question, is how do we find the same info for an Exchange Personal Archive mailbox? And it would have to be WhenCreated, not when it was moved onto its current database, which is what I seem to be finding when I pull MailboxFolderStatistics, per [this link.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/28d4ecd4-15d4-41bc-917a-872b324430ea/archive-mailbox-creation-date-in-exchange-2010?forum=exchange2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's the answer from Microsoft PSS:

> After confirm with escalation engineer and perform a lot of research
>   and test, we regret to say that we don’t have a command currently to
>   retrieve the creation date of an archive mailbox. Sorry for the
>   inconvenience.